# Scrolling a UICollectionView only with a button press

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` and its cells contains questions and `UITextField` that users must write in. I want to add a button onto the `UICollectionViewCell`, that the users must press that will scroll them to the next `UICollectionViewCell`. Is this possible and how do I do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the button tag to hold the value of the index row.
So in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method add:

```
cell.nextButton.tag = indexPath.row
```

Then to scroll to a certain index you can call this when the button is pressed:

```
[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath  atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sorry It's late, But today I am working on same functionality.**

Please use below **code** and it's working.

1) Add line in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.

```
btnNext.tag = indexPath.item;
```

2) Create `method` for scroll to next `cell`.

```
-(IBAction)actionNext:(UIButton *)sender{
    if(sender.tag == 0 || sender.tag == nil){
        btnNext.tag = 1;
    }
    if(sender.tag > arrImage.count){
        [self.colView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:arrImage.count-1 inSection:0]  atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:YES];
    }else{
        [self.colView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0]  atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:YES];
    }

}
```

Please ask me if you have any question. :)